# Voltage seen at load which has open circuit in parallel

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, transmission-line

If I send a sinusoidal signal down a transmission line, say with a source and line impedance of 50 ohms. Then if I have a 50 ohm load, in theory, there are absolutely no reflections.

If however, I have an open circuit stub off 'after' the load (so an open circuit in parallel with the load), what would my load 'see'?

I see it as the following, the open circuit causes a reflection of equal magnitude and direction. This interferes and causes double the voltage to be received at the load (standing wave). Is this correct?

This is assuming that my transmission line is very short compared to my wavelength.

Edit: changed resistance to impedance for accuracy.

Comment: That answer depends on the length of the stub and frequency/wavelength of your signal.

Comment: And the velocity of the signal propagation in the wire. Not all transmission lines are equal.

Comment: It's not called line resistance; it's called characteristic impedance. There is a big difference.

Comment: @SteveSh, in this case, the stub can be assumed to be very small in comparison to wavelength. Talking less than a mm stub, to a wavelength of hundreds of metres

Comment: Then it would have virtually no effect. General rule of thumb is you have to start accounting for transmission line effects when the line is around ~1/10 the size of the signal's wavelength.

A 1mm stub is nothing to a 100m wavelength signal.

Comment: @Michael, is this also true for power transfer. Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: The 1mm open stub would have no effect on the voltage reflections, as it is electrically small. A stub 25 meters long however, that is electrically "long" compared to your signal, that would affect reflections/power transfer